# SQL Gen'd login identifier

Tags: sql, variables, dynamic, authentication

I'm trying to do this

```
declare @aspAccountName varchar(30);
SET @aspAccountName=HOST_NAME() + '\ASPNET';

IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @aspAccountName)
    CREATE LOGIN (SELECT @aspAccountName) FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
```

But it says 'Incorrect syntax near '@aspAccountName' - any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to write the `CREATE LOGIN` portion as dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(200)

SET @sql = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + @aspAccountName + N' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid going down that route but you're right, it works. Anyone any ideas WHY my original example doesn't work?